# How can I keep using DLCs purchased on an old account with my new account?

Tags: ps3, psn

I have made a new Playstation Network (PSN) account for a fresh start. I know you can't delete a PSN account, so I deactivated it, but all my *Batman: Arkham Origins* DLCs are still on my previous account. I do not want to create a new user and use my previous account on it because I don't want to have a useless user.

Is is it worth me making a new account for those dlcs?

Comment: You might have to contact sony to get them moved over to your other psn?

Answer (score 4):

You *will* need an account on the PS3 that owns those DLCs in order to be able to play those games/use those DLCs (or download them in the first place if you don't have them locally).

You could contact Sony and ask if they can move over the purchases, but I'm not sure if they do this (they definitely don't change PSN IDs).

The easiest way around this is to simply keep that account on the PSN as a user and just set your PS3 to auto-sign in as the new user. The old user account will exist but will basically only be used to validate your DLC/games, so it really won't clutter up anything unless you change users often.

Comment: If you do contact sony do you have to tell then your account details ?

Comment: @OliverTighe most likely your email and other details like recovery questions to identity your are the account holder but that's if they will do it, if they don't they wont get details

Comment: And will my account need to be activated ?

Comment: @OliverTighe I don't know about that part...I didn't know deactivating *accounts* was a thing, I've only deactivated *devices* for that account, which *does* prevent you from accessing DLC/games tied to that account.

Comment: Ok that's what I mean